# Javascript create an array from randomizing an array values without duplicates?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I have to generate a array of length 3 says [3,2,1].. by random from the array of length 4 says [1,2,3,4] using java script.

```
  var ele=[1,2,3,4];
```

I have to generate a new array var three=new Array(3);

the value of the array "three" should be randomized without duplicate from array "ele" .

```
 ex three=[3,2,4]...
```

Here is the code I tried,

```
var tempArray=[1,2,3,4];
var set_bf =[];
for(var k=0;k<tempArray.length;k++){
    var rand=(Math.round((Math.random()*tempArray.length)));
    set_bf.push(rand);
    console.log('male :'+rand);
    var idx = tempArray.indexOf(rand);
    if(idx!=-1) tempArray.splice(idx, 1);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you running into trouble? What's your best effort look like? SO isn't a code writing service. :-)

Comment: yes the array "three" should be created once from the "ele"

Comment: chk the code that i have tried its randomize the same

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to select random entries from another array ?

```
var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
```

This will give you a random element from the array `myArray` That should at least point you in the right direction